# Python: syntax error with import

Tags: python, python-import

I have a python script technically named `/home/pi/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit_BMP085/Adafruit_BMP085_example.py`

The first line of this script is

```
from Adafruit_BMP085 import BMP085
```

Also located in this directory is a python file named Adafruit_BMP085 that has a function BMP085.

I want to create a python script in `/home/pi` that imports the same BMP085.

I've tried:

```
from /home/pi/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit_BMP085/Adafruit_BMP085 import BMP085
```

But this just gives me a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried various syntax combinations of this same method, but cannot find one that works.

Comment: try importing `sys` and doing `sys.path.append("path/to/file")` before you import

Comment: Why would this *not* be an ´ImportError´?

Comment: Because python.

Answer (score 14):

You need to add the `/home/pi/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code` path to the module search path in [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path):

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/pi/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code')
from Adafruit_BMP085 import BMP085
```

or move the `Adafruit_BMP085` package to a directory already in your `sys.path`.

The directory of the script itself is also part of the `sys.path`, so you could also run:

```
$ cd /home/pi/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code
$ cp Adafruit_BMP085/Adafruit_BMP085_example.py .
$ python Adafruit_BMP085_example.py
```

Comment: But Python actually uses that list to determine the import path?

Answer (score 3):

OP's question is generically titled but the post is specific to a particular `import` case.

In my case, I was getting a `SyntaxError` when having a very standard `import` scenario. The error was directly pointing at the import statement, very confusingly.

What was actually happening was that there was a (very subtle) syntax error in the module being imported. Fixing that error resolved the SyntaxError during import.

This was very confusing because Python reported `SyntaxError` on the import line, rather than forwarding to the internal module's syntax problem (which, I believe, *sometimes* it does); even a generic `ImportError` would've been more helpful. I wasted time thinking it was some module/path naming issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was a combination of

1. leaving an open string in a module (the bug...)
2. importing the module within a *try/except* block

It happened when using a device with *MicroPython*, and these were the symptoms:

(1) `import mymodule` from the *REPL prompt* **didn't show any problem**!

(2) running this code from my main module:

```
try:
    import mymodule
except Exception as e:
    print(e, '|', e.errno, '|', e.value, '|', e.args)
```

was giving this result at the 'import' line, without revealing the problematic source:

```
invalid syntax | invalid syntax | invalid syntax | ('invalid syntax',)
```

(3) but when I did a **direct** import from the main module, I found the problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "mymodule.py", line 126
```

so... be careful when wrapping import with try/except

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. The problem first occured when upgrading to **Jessie on RPI**. The cause was probably within the pathing.
Added below line to Python program:

```
sys.path.append('/home/pi/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit_BMP085')
```

Now problem solved.

Comment: Updating to Jessie should not be affecting what statements python2 or python3 considers syntax errors.  It should be operating system independent.

Comment: @EricLeschinski yes, though I'm wondering - both answers are the same and try to solve an error of a missing/not found package, not a syntax error. How come the other answer is that high up in votes, meanwhile this answer which is basically the same is negative? None of them answer the question.